# split array elements from python into separate HTML tables based on specified attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, django-templates

I have a Drilling table containing, daily drilling and all time drilling record. we have project in which drill and the corresponding client in each record. now i am building a report in which i need to view a daily summary of all drilling PER Client rather. More precisely i need to see a list where i have client name, followed by the number of drilling records for that client (any number), then the total of  the meters that were drilled.

In my code i get a filter based on day then client, after that i get the sum for all drilling of a particular client. all the data are correct and and i am getting all record for that day with their client. I put them all in arrays and send to HTML template. when i send it to HTML they all get in the table but formated in only one table row...my problem is how can i best format it the way i explained at the beginning of the question

this the view:

```
def report(request):
today = date.today()
clt_ = []
clt_day_t_m_ = []
result = []
client = []
drill_date = []
auger = []
vehicle = []
project_name = []
shift = []
meters_drilled = []
targetmeters = []
driller = []
comment = []

m_p_obj_day = Drilling.objects.filter(drilling_date=today)
_total = m_p_obj_day.aggregate(Sum('ms_drilled'))['ms_drilled__sum']

for ma_por_obj_day in m_p_obj_day:
    client_ma_por_obj_day = Client.objects.filter(clt_nme=ma_por_obj_day.client)

    for clt_s in client_ma_por_obj_day:
        clt_.append(clt_s.clt_nme)
clt_s_=list(set(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(clt_))))
_items = ""
for f in clt_s_:#
    _client_obj = Client.objects.filter(clt_name=f)
    _items = m_p_obj_day.filter(client=_client_obj)
    for i in _items:
        client.append(i.clt)
        drill_date.append(i.drill_dte)
        auger.append(i.auger)
        vehicle.append(i.vehicle)
        project_name.append(i.prjt_nme)
        shift.append(i.shift)
        meters_drilled.append(i.mtrs_drilled)
        targetmeters.append(i.targetmeters_drilled)
        driller.append(i.driller)
        comment.append(i.comment)
        ut_ = m_p_obj_day.filter(client=_client_obj).aggregate(Sum('ms_drilled'))['ms_drilled__sum']
        clt_day_t_m_.append(u)

client_ = "\n".join(map(str, client))
drill_date_ = "\n".join(map(str, drill_date))
vehicle_ = "\n".join(map(str, vehicle))
auger_ = "\n".join(map(str, auger))
project_name_ = "\n".join(map(str, project_name))
shift_ = "\n".join(map(str, shift))
meters_drilled_ = "\n".join(map(str, meters_drilled))
targetmeters_drilled_ = "\n".join(map(str, targetmeters))
driller_ = "\n  ".join(map(str, driller))
comment_ = "\n".join(map(str, comment))
clt_d_total_m_ = "\n".join(map(str, clt_day_t_m_))

context = {
    "_total": _total,
    "_items": _items,
    "m_p_obj_day": m_p_obj_day,
    "clt_s_": clt_s_,
    "clt_d_total_m_": clt_d_total_m_,
    "client_": client_,
    "drill_date_": drill_date_,
    "auger_": auger_,
    "vehicle_": vehicle_,
    "project_name_": project_name_,
    "shift_": shift_,
    "meters_drilled_": meters_drilled_,
    "targetmeters": targetmeters,
    "driller_": driller_,
    "comment_": comment_,
}
return render(request, "jourly_report.html", context)
```

This is sample of a template portion:

```
        <thead>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Drill Date</th>
            <th>Auger</th>
            <th>Vehicle km</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Shift</th>
            <th>Meters Drilled</th>
            <th>Target meters</th>
            <th>Driller</th>
            <th>Comment</th>

            <th>Total for Each Client</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for all_item in all_items %}
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ client_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ drill_date_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ auger_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ vehicle_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ project_name_ | linebreaks}}</td>
                    <td>{{ shift_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ meters_drilled_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ targetmeters_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ driller_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td>{{ comment_ | linebreaks }}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 13px!important; font-weight: bold!important; background-color: #BDBDBD;">{{ client_day_total_m_ | linebreaks }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <thead >
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Grand Total Meters Drilled: </th>
                    <th style="font-size: 14px!important; font-weight: bold!important; background-color: #FA5858;">{{ _total }}</th>
                </thead>
```

as you can see on the image all the drillings are all in the same column or data cell. they are not in differents rows. i want any suggestion to help have access individual items in these array and put them in each of them their rows then create a table for each client where we will put only records of that client int the table (each client has their table)... if i was not clear please let me know.

[image: display of the tamplate and drilling data of today]

Comment: i really need help. i am stuck at how to do it. Please HELP!!!!

Comment: ayone help in suggesting any way around this please!!!